# How to change VBA code to work with cells under the first one?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

This code (an answer provided by the previous question I had in another post and have to ask another question in a separate post) works for A1, B1, D1, and E1. What exactly do I change to make it work for either 1) all the cell under them or 2) a select range of cells under them. In other words, make it work for A2, B2, D2, E2, and A3, B3, D3, E3. If you need anymore information or questions, please ask and I'll do my best to make it more clear. Thank you in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 And (Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2) Then
    'new val
    a1 = Range("A1").Value
    b1 = Range("B1").Value
    newVal = Range("D1").Value

    'disable events and undo
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    'old val
    oldVal = Range("D1").Value

    'diff between new and old val
    diff = newVal - oldVal

    Range("A1").Value = a1
    Range("B1").Value = b1
    Range("E1").Value = diff

    're-enable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Any time you need to change rows or make something dynamic.  Just assign a variable to it and substitute the variable for the HARD CODED value.  Then you can perform mathematical operations on the variable, usually adding 1 to it, and looping the same procedure with the variable name as the ROW.  In this case, you can just have the variable assigned by the changed cell's row, or 'Target.Row'.  The rest is pretty much the same, and whatever cell you change will dictate then what row is to be manipulated.

Comment: Your code is replacing the initial values with the same values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just take the same incoming target and assign a variable by the ROW property of the target.  Then every Range(A1) you have, you replace the 1 with the variable.  "lRow".  You change the initial IF statement to allow ANY row, and still check to make sure it's column 1 or 2.

I also renamed the a1, b1, to aVal and bVal.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim lRow As Long

    If Target.column = 1 Or Target.column = 2 Then
        'new val
        lRow = Target.row
        aVal = Range("A" & lRow).Value
        bVal = Range("B" & lRow).Value
        newVal = Range("D" & lRow).Value

        'disable events and undo
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        'old val
        oldVal = Range("D" & lRow).Value

        'diff between new and old val
        diff = newVal - oldVal

        Range("A" & lRow).Value = aVal
        Range("B" & lRow).Value = bVal
        Range("E" & lRow).Value = diff

        're-enable events
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Mr. Rosenburg, you sir, are a boss!